# How to make `devtools` not re-install installed packages

Tags: r, devtools

When installing on a fresh machine (Docker), when I do

```
devtools::install_github('repo/package_A')
devtools::install_github('repo/package_B_that_imports_A')
```

then package A will be re-installed when the second command is run.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of this

Comment: It's happening on my private repos, so not something that can be reproduced in the wild...

Comment: Good question, I am having the same question. not sure sorce=FALSE is an option or not